# Ephemeral key issue with OpenIddict

Tags: openid-connect, openid, openiddict

Using a Ephemeral key in OpenIddict configuration, when you have the server running for period of time, the jwt configuration changes on:
https://serverIp/.well-known/jwks

you can see this configuration changes on the kid values
"kid": "YKAPTPYELUM23G4M2D6NVMAGBAQRBRNHUZBAPEJN"

That means the resources validation will throws allways a 401 messages after the kid changes.

Does anyone knows if there is a setting to disable this kid regeneration without use  a static SecurityKey?¿

Answer (score 1):

API JWT libraries are meant to be coded to cope with this automatically:

- Every time an API request is received, the most common usage is for there to be a `kid` field in the JWT header
- A library looks in its cache and if this value is not found the library will download JWKS keys, then cache them for subsequent API requests
- Meanwhile an Authorization Server such as openiddict is free to change its token signing keys, on demand or automatically, as long as new keys get new `kid` values

Here is some [example API code](https://github.com/curityio/kotlin-api-jwt-validation/blob/main/src/main/java/io/curity/example/secureapi/OAuthFilter.kt) that works like this, and JWT libraries in other technologies work equivalently. It is worth testing in your own APIs though, to be sure.